# Kinematics problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

I'm on earth and we have two spaceships $A,B$. They can instantaneously accelerate to certain velocities $v_A,v_B$.

We want to travel to another planet which is $\Delta x$ lightseconds away, and we want the ships to arrive at the same time. The universe as such doesn't change during the traveling time.

How much time $\Delta t$ must the more advanced spaceship $B$ wait to start, after spaceship $A$ took off?

Comment: What do grandchildren have to do with this problem, or for that matter relativity? As written this is just a question in basic kinematics.

Comment: @MichaelBrown: Okay the time itself isn't so interesting. Put differently, I'm interested in how $v_B$ is bounded by $v_A$ and how both dependent on $\Delta x$, if we want the slow person to make the trip in a lifetime (let's call the average lifetime $T$, e.g. $60 years$) and the fast person starting $n$ generations (e.g. $n=7$) after the first, taking into account that he also needs to meet the other person.

Comment: So you want A to take the trip in a proper time of 60 years and B to wait ~140 years, make the same trip and arrive at the same time as A? As long as $\Delta x$ is at least 140ly, anything will work. For instance if the planet is exactly 140ly away, $v_A=(2\sqrt10/7) c$ and $v_B=c$

Comment: Correction, meant to write $\sqrt187/14$ not $2\sqrt10/7$

Comment: Why did you reject [this edit by Deer Hunter](http://physics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/20957)? "Homework" is certainly not a reply.

Comment: @DImension10AbhimanyuPS: I did reject it because it's not homework. But I don't really care, and I agree that it looks homeworky.

Comment: . @NickKidman   It does fall into the homework cateegory given in by the                                                                                                                                                                                mneta post.

Answer (score 1):

Special relativity isn't even required here since we can simply view the entire operation from either earth or the other planet, for which the velocities $v_A$ and $v_B$ as well as the distance $\Delta x$ are given. Therefor, $\Delta t$ is simply the difference between the (classical) travel time of both spaceships:
$$\Delta t=\frac{\Delta x}{v_A}-\frac{\Delta x}{v_B}$$